# Trying to create a filter-by-column table. Why isn't my js working?

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and am trying to create a table where each column can be filtered. I've pieced together this code from JSFiddle resources, and it works beautifully on their website, but I can't get it to work anywhere else. It references an external js, and I think that's where it might be going wrong.

Here is the link to the original resource: 
http://jsfiddle.net/eCqG3/3229/

And here is my version:

```js
var table2_Props = {
  col_0: "select",
  col_1: "select",
  col_2: "select",
  col_3: "select",
  display_all_text: " [ Show all ] ",
  sort_select: true
};
var tf2 = setFilterGrid("table2", table2_Props);
```

```css
 table.table2 {
 background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #4e4e4e;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
```

```html
<script src="http://tablefilter.free.fr/TableFilter/tablefilter_all_min.js"></script>
<p>Add a drop-down filter, define its first option, sort it and remove a filter</p>
<table id="table2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Account Type</th>
    <th>Form Name</th>
    <th>Form Type</th>
    <th>Account Name</th>
    <th>Special Instructions</th>
  </tr>
  
  
  

</table>
```

Thanks so much for your help - I'm really stuck!

Comment: Where are you putting your js code? Make sure the external script was loaded before your code is executed.

Comment: I put it at the top of <body>.

Comment: Your JS is probably executing before the DOM has finished loading.  Put it at the bottom.

Comment: I think there is a problem loading the javascript in stackoverflow.  I'm going to do a test below since no one else has responded with a solution.

Comment: My first guess is Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB).  It is an http resource.

Comment: I was able to get it working in the **stackoverflow snippet editor** if I put the CSS and Javascript inline, but I could not post the answer because the size limitation of the post.

Comment: This [blog post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/) by Nick Craver has some info about the Cross Origin problem with **stackoverflow snippets**

Answer (score 0):

Your script it's being executed before the DOM it's ready.

Place your script just before the ending `</body>` tag or use this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // your js code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is not loading.

[image: error loading javascript]